# Generate the Stack Overflow logo

Tags: code-challenge, popularity-contest, graphical-output

**The challenge is to generate an image similar to the StackOverflow logo:**

[image]

**The output must contain:**

- Image size 64*64 or greater
- A gray |__| shaped base
- A curved segmented stack coming up from the base. The segments will fade from gray to orange, and make a ~90 degree right turn. The number of segments should be between 5 and 7, with 6 being preferred.

Note: For ascii displays that lack color, use a '0' character to represent gray, and '9' for orange. '1' to '8' would represent the shades in-between.

**Restrictions:**

- You must *generate* the image. Loading images or storing them in the code/binary is not allowed.

**Additional rules/information:**

- The image is not required to be identical to the logo, however it must be recognizable as it.
- The method of display is up to you. Saving it to an image file or displaying on the screen are both acceptable.

**Judging/winning criteria:**

- Accuracy of the image is the primary condition
- Elegance of generation is the secondary condition

Comment: The official [16x16 px version](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) of the logo actually has only 4 bars in the stack.

Comment: I'm not sure what it was like in 2012, but by today's standards this is not an *objective* winning criterion. I guess the best fix (which also wouldn't affect the winner), would be to turn this into a [tag:popularity-contest] and move the judging criteria to voting guidelines.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I count SIX. Also, that's 32x32px.

Comment: @mbomb007: [It looked different back in 2012.](http://web.archive.org/web/20120110010737/http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## Mathematica

```
Graphics[{
   Gray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {78, 50}],
   White, Rectangle[{9, 9}, {69, 50}]}
  ~Join~
  Table[{
    Blend[{Gray, Orange}, x/5],
    Rotate[
     Translate[
      Rectangle[{16, 16}, {61, 25}],
      {0.25x^3 + 0.6x^2 - 0.4x, -0.53x^3 + 3.26x^2 + 12x}],
     -0.05x^2 - 0.04x]},
   {x, 0, 5}]]
```

I decided to prettify my answer after realizing this isn't code golf. Whoops!

Screenshot:

[image: Stack Overflow logo]

In related news, I also created what I think the Stack Overflow logo might look like in... ***THE FUTURE***:

[image: THE FUTURE IS NOW]

Here's the code if anyone wants to play around with it (sorry for the mess):

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[],
   Opacity[1],
   RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 0.2], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {78, 4, 50}],
   Cuboid[{0, 4, 0}, {4, 45, 50}],
    Cuboid[{74, 4, 0}, {78, 45, 50}],
   Opacity[1]}
  ~Join~
  Fold[Join, {},
   Table[{Hue[0.15 - i/5/12, i/3, 1],
     Translate[
      Rotate[
       Scale[Cuboid[{16, 16, 16}, {61, 25, 25}], {1, .3, .3}],
       (-.05 ((i*2 - 1.5)*1.25)^2 - .04 ((i*2)*1.2)), {0.3, 
        0.8, -1}, {(16 + 61)/2, (16 + 25)/2, (16 + 25)/2}],
      {-((i*2)^2 - (i*2)*4)/2, (i*2)^2*3/2, 0}]},
    {i, 0, 4.5, 0.05}]], Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, 
 Background -> White, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: Awesome, but the proportion sheet - box would look better, imho, with a smaller box with less thick border.

Comment: Very nice! This community could use your skills ;-) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hehe `Out[404]`

Answer (score 23):

### Javascript (650)

I wrote a quine that reads the characters in the function, and replaces non-space characters with a number from 0-9.

```
(function a(){
l=[
                   1,
                    1,
            11,      1,
             11,     1,
               11,    1,
       11,      11,   1,
         11,      11,
           11,
   11,       1111,
     1111,
0,       11111111, 0,
0, 11,             0,
0,   111111111111, 0,
0,                 0,
0, 11111111111111, 0,
0,                 0,
000000000000000000000]

b=a.toString().split("[")[1].split("]")[0].split(""),i=-1
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=
b.map(function(c){
++i
if(c==" "||c=="\n")return c
if(c!=0)c=9-Math.floor((i/b.length)*10)
if(b[i-1]=="0")c=0
return"<span class='c"+c+"'>"+c+"</span>"
}).join("")
})()
```

This outputs this ASCII art:

```
                   99
                    88
            888      88
             777     77
               766    66
       666      666   66
         555      555
           555
   444       44444
     44444
00       333333333 00
00 333             00
00   2222222222222 00
00                 00
00 111111111111111 00
00                 00
000000000000000000000
```

which can be colored with a css stylesheet if you like

```
  span{
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .c0, .c1{
    color: #222;
  }
  .c2{
    color: #765;
  }
  .c3{
    color: #976;
  }
  .c4{
    color: #A64;
  }
  .c6, .c5{
    color: #D51;
  }
  .c8, .c9, .c7{
    color: #F60;
  }
```

You can [see it in action on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/esunuc/8).

Here is a screenshot, in case the link dies:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

### SVG (347 characters)

Based on [Sir_Lagsalot's version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4640), with strokes instead of fills.  Besides shaving off a few chars, the code is simpler and the output looks better scaled up.

```
<svg width="66" height="85" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g stroke-width="7" fill="none">
<path stroke="gray" d="m4,50v31h49V50M12,69h33"/>
<path stroke="#a86" d="m12,57 33,3"/>
<path stroke="#b95" d="m14,42 32,9"/>
<path stroke="#c82" d="m22,24 27,19"/>
<path stroke="#e80" d="m37,9 18,27"/>
<path stroke="#f71" d="m58,1 4,32"/>
</g></svg>
```

[Link to SVG image](http://vyznev.net/misc/so_logo.svg).

Rendered to PNG (at natural size and scaled up x2 and x3):

[image: Natural size]    
[image: Scaled up x2]    
[image: Scaled up x3]

**Edit:** Finally got around to fixing the off-by-one error that caused the sides of the box not to line up.  Also tweaked the line thickness and end point placement a bit, and added explicit width and height to avoid the bottom and right edges being cropped too tight.  It now looks a *lot* closer to the official logo.

Answer (score 18):

### Haskell w/Gloss

```
import Graphics.Gloss

picture = translate 0 (-50) $ pictures [stack, base 150 60 20]

stack = translate 0 30 $ pictures [item n | n <- [0..5]]

item n = bend 200 (-10*n) $ color (fade grey orange (n/5)) box
  where box = rectangleSolid 110 20

base width height thickness = color grey $ pictures [left, right, bottom]
  where bottom = rectangleSolid width thickness
        left = translate (width / 2) (height / 2) side
        right = translate (-width / 2) (height / 2) side

        side = rectangleSolid thickness (height + thickness)

bend radius angle = translate radius 0 . rotate angle . translate (-radius) 0

fade from to alpha = mixColors (1-alpha) alpha from to

grey = greyN 0.5
```

[image: Screenshot]

[Paste the code here to see it in action](http://dac4.designacourse.com:8000/draw), or add the following line to compile it (requires [Gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss)).

```
main = display (InWindow "Stack Overflow" (512, 512) (10, 10)) white picture
```

Answer (score 15):

### SVG (333 characters)

I've created a SVG image that generates a 67x68 version of the logo in 333 characters:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill="grey" d="m0,53v34h53V53h-5v29H5V53M9,69h33v6H11v-6"/>
<path fill="#a86" d="m12,56 31,3-1,6-31-3"/>
<path fill="#b95" d="m15,41 31,9-2,6-31-8"/>
<path fill="#c82" d="m22,25 28,17-3,5-28-17"/>
<path fill="#e80" d="m38,8 19,27-5,4-19-27"/>
<path fill="#f71" d="m62,0 5,32-6,1-5-32"/>
</svg>
```

[Link for small SVG image](http://lags.leetcode.net/logo.svg)
[Link for large SVG image](http://lags.leetcode.net/logo_large.svg)

[image: Example]

Comment: I wonder if using stroked paths wouldn't be even shorter.

Answer (score 13):

### LaTeX

Using the TikZ and PGF packages.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\xdefinecolor{col1}{RGB}{167, 149, 116}
\xdefinecolor{col2}{RGB}{189, 153, 87}
\xdefinecolor{col3}{RGB}{211, 157, 57}
\xdefinecolor{col4}{RGB}{233, 161, 28}
\xdefinecolor{col5}{RGB}{255, 165, 0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, fill=gray] (-1,0.5) -- (-1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,0.5) -- (-0.1,0.5) -- (-0.1,0.1) -- (-0.9,0.1) -- (-0.9,0.5) -- (-1,0.5);
\draw[gray, fill=gray] (-0.8,0.3) rectangle(-0.2,0.2); 
\draw[col1, fill=col1, xshift=0.3pt, yshift=3pt,  rotate around={-15:(0.2,0.2)}] (-0.8,0.3) rectangle(-0.2,0.2); 
\draw[col2, fill=col2, xshift=0.5pt, yshift=6pt,  rotate around={-30:(0.2,0.2)}] (-0.8,0.3) rectangle(-0.2,0.2); 
\draw[col3, fill=col3, xshift=0.8pt, yshift=9pt,  rotate around={-45:(0.2,0.2)}] (-0.8,0.3) rectangle(-0.2,0.2); 
\draw[col4, fill=col4, xshift=1.3pt, yshift=12pt, rotate around={-60:(0.2,0.2)}] (-0.8,0.3) rectangle(-0.2,0.2); 
\draw[col5, fill=col5, xshift=2.1pt, yshift=14pt, rotate around={-75:(0.2,0.2)}] (-0.8,0.3) rectangle(-0.2,0.2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX Logo]

Answer (score 9):

## CSS+JavaScript (HTML div based)

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

div { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 20px; background-color: red; }
.s { background-color: gray; }
#d0,#d2 { width: 20px; height: 70px; }
#d0 { left: 20px; top: 160px; }
#d1 { left: 20px; top: 230px; width: 160px; }
#d2 { left: 160px; top: 160px; }

.e { -moz-transform-origin: 200% center; -ms-transform-origin: 200% center; -o-transform-origin: 200% center; -webkit-transform-origin: 200% center; transform-origin: 200% center; }
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        $('body').append($('<div/>').attr('id', 'd' + i).attr('class', i < 3 ? 's' : 'e'))
    
    $('.e').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({
            left: (50 - i * 3) + 'px',
            top: '200px',
            backgroundColor: '#' + (i + 10).toString(16) + 'a' + (10 - i * 2).toString(16),
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + (i * 15) + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + (i * 15) + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + (i * 15) + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + (i * 15) + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotate(' + (i * 15) + 'deg)'
        });
    });
});
```

Sample run: http://jsfiddle.net/ryzBx/

Sample rendering (Firefox 14):
[image: StackExchange Logo]

Answer (score 8):

### Javascript (<strike>a lot of</strike> 814 characters)

```
window.onload = function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("cgCanvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.moveTo(60,140);
                context.lineTo(60,190);
                context.moveTo(57.5,190);
                context.lineTo(137.5,190);
                context.moveTo(135,140);
                context.lineTo(135,190);
                context.lineWidth = 5;
                context.strokeStyle = "rgb(94,94,94)";
                context.stroke();
                for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
                    context.beginPath();
                    var b=1;
                    var a=1;
                    if(i==5) {
                        a=3;
                        b=1.3;
                    }
                    else if(i==4)
                        a==2;
                    x=94+i*9;
                    y=94-i*5;
                    z=95-i*19;
                    context.moveTo(122.5+i*i,180-i*15);
                    context.lineTo(72.5+i*i+i*i*b,180-i*15-i*i*i+i*i*a);
                    context.lineWidth = 8;
                    context.strokeStyle = 'rgb('+ x +','+ y +','+ z +')';
                    context.stroke();
                }
            };
```

It ain't pretty but looks a bit like the SO logo.
Test fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/elssar/jcYtg/2/

Comment: That can be golfed down quite a bit if you change the name of context to something more simple.

Comment: Hey there, I golfed it down a little bit for you, it now is on 749 chars: http://jsfiddle.net/jcYtg/5/ -- I liked this approach! Very nice.

Comment: 706 now: http://jsfiddle.net/jcYtg/12/ -- wanted to change the repetition of i's or the rgb but only messed it up, so didn't change that part.

Comment: (Sorry for the spam, this is the last one, I promise). Minimized: http://jsfiddle.net/jcYtg/13/ 501 chars.

Comment: Thanks @Alpha It's going to take some time getting used to golfing the code, most times looking at golfed code makes me want to kill the person who wrote it(sorry). About the approach was basically trial & error as I was too lazy to do the math. Would've been better to use concentric circles or even better concentric ellipses to get the positions of the stacks.

Answer (score 7):

### C#/GDI+

I was surprised when I noticed there's no C# answer here. So here's one. This is not an ingenious way of drawing the logo, and is not a short solution either. But gets the required output.

[image: Generated logo and the original StackOverflow logo]

You can check my blog post out to download the full working solution → 
http://guganeshan.com/blog/stackoverflow-logo-using-csharp-and-gdi.html

```
public class SOLogo
{
    private float _rotateValue;
    private float _xValueForTransformation;
    private float _yValueForTransformation;

    int _containerWidth;
    int _containerHeight;
    float _lineThickness;
    int _paddingWithinContainer;
    int _elementStartY;

    public SOLogo(float rotateValue, float xValueForTransformation, float yValueForTransformation)
    {
        // Values used to position and rotate the overflowing elements.
        _rotateValue = rotateValue;
        _xValueForTransformation  = xValueForTransformation;
        _yValueForTransformation = yValueForTransformation;
    }

    public void DrawLogo(Graphics g, int startX, int startY)
    {
        // Backup the current smoothing mode to apply later.
        var SmoothingMoodBackup = g.SmoothingMode;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        // Values for the container box.
        _containerWidth = 94;
        _containerHeight = 61;
        _lineThickness = 11f;
        _paddingWithinContainer = 15;

        // Y value of the position where the 1st overflowing element starts.
        _elementStartY = 0;

        // Starting point of the 'container' - Top point of the line on the left-> |_|
        Point pointContainerLineStart = new Point(startX, startY);

        Point pointContainer1stLineEnd = new Point(pointContainerLineStart.X, pointContainerLineStart.Y); // Start with the previous
        pointContainer1stLineEnd.Offset(0, _containerHeight); // Offset "Y"

        Point pointContainer2ndLineEnd = new Point(pointContainer1stLineEnd.X, pointContainer1stLineEnd.Y); // Start with the previous
        pointContainer2ndLineEnd.Offset(_containerWidth, 0); // Offset "X"

        Point pointContainer3rdLineEnd = new Point(pointContainer2ndLineEnd.X, pointContainer2ndLineEnd.Y); // Start with the previous
        pointContainer3rdLineEnd.Offset(0, 0 - _containerHeight); // Offset "Y" (negative)

        GraphicsPath pathOfBox = new GraphicsPath();
        pathOfBox.AddLine(pointContainerLineStart, pointContainer1stLineEnd); // Left line. Top to bottom
        pathOfBox.AddLine(pointContainer1stLineEnd, pointContainer2ndLineEnd); // Bottom line. Left to right
        pathOfBox.AddLine(pointContainer2ndLineEnd, pointContainer3rdLineEnd); // Right line. Bottom to top

        Pen thickPen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, _lineThickness);
        Color elementColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Gray);

        // Draw the 'container'
        g.DrawPath(thickPen, pathOfBox);

        // Increase the size of the pen to draw the elements inside the container
        thickPen.Width = _lineThickness += 3;
        // "Y" - position of the 1st element
        _elementStartY = startY + 38;

        // The following section draws the overflowing elements

        Point pointElement1Left = new Point(startX + _paddingWithinContainer, _elementStartY);
        Point pointElement1Right = new Point((startX + _containerWidth) - _paddingWithinContainer, _elementStartY);

        // Six colors of the overflowing elements
        var colors = new Color[] {
            Color.Gray,                 Color.FromArgb(-6911615),   Color.FromArgb(-4417693),
            Color.FromArgb(-2848227),   Color.FromArgb(-554957),    Color.FromArgb(-688847)
        };

        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        {
            thickPen.Color = colors[x];
            pointElement1Left = new Point(startX + _paddingWithinContainer, _elementStartY);
            pointElement1Right = new Point((startX + _containerWidth) - _paddingWithinContainer, _elementStartY);
            g.DrawLine(thickPen, pointElement1Left, pointElement1Right);
            g.RotateTransform(_rotateValue);
            g.TranslateTransform(_xValueForTransformation, _yValueForTransformation);
        }

        pathOfBox.Dispose();
        thickPen.Dispose();

        // Restore the smoothing mood that was backed up before we started this method.
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMoodBackup;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm **super** late to the game here, but I was surprised no one did a CSS version of this. This is definitely not a competitive answer when it comes to character count (1,195) but the final product is pretty accurate.

Written in Safari (9.0) and tested in Chrome (45.0.2454.93) and Firefox (40.0.3).

```css
body {
    padding: 100px 40px;
}
.base {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 8px solid #818286;
    border-top: none;
}
.container {
    bottom: 28px;
    left: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
.line {
    width: 48px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.line:nth-child(1n) {
    background: #ff7a15;
    bottom: 23px;
    left: 45px;
    transform: rotate(80deg)
}
.line:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #ff8907;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    transform: rotate(55deg)
}
.line:nth-child(3n) {
    background: #d48c28;
    bottom: 19px;
    left: 10px;
    transform: rotate(30deg)
}
.line:nth-child(4n) {
    background: #c19653;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: 3px;
    transform: rotate(16deg)
}
.line:nth-child(5n) {
    background: #a78b6e;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.line:nth-child(6n) {
    background: #818286;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript + jQuery & SVG - 250

```
$('body').html('<svg><g stroke-width="6" fill="none"$grey" d="m3,51v31h47V53M10,70h33"/$#a86" d="m10,57 33,3"/$#b95" d="m13,42 31,9"/$#c82" d="m20,25 28,17"/$#e80" d="m34,9 19,27"/$#f71" d="m56,1 4,32"/></g></svg>'.replace(/\$/g, '><path stroke="'))​
```

I took Ilmari Karonen's SVG and used JavaScript to replace `$`s with `><path stroke="` effectively shortening it even with the overhead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP w/ GD

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(67,68);
$white = imagecolorallocate($img,0xff,0xff,0xff);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($img,0x80,0x81,0x85);
$orng1 = imagecolorallocate($img,0xa6,0x8a,0x6e);
$orng2 = imagecolorallocate($img,0xc0,0x95,0x53);
$orng3 = imagecolorallocate($img,0xd3,0x8b,0x28);
$orng4 = imagecolorallocate($img,0xfd,0x88,0x08);
$orng5 = imagecolorallocate($img,0xfe,0x7a,0x15);
imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,67,68,$white);

//container
imagefilledrectangle($img,7,41,10,65,$grey);
imagefilledrectangle($img,10,61,44,65,$grey);
imagefilledrectangle($img,41,61,44,41,$grey);

// stack levels
imagefilledrectangle($img,14,52,37,56,$grey); //1st level
imagefilledpolygon($img,array(14,42,14,47,37,49,37,44),4,$orng1);
imagefilledpolygon($img,array(16,32,15,36,37,42,38,38),4,$orng2);
imagefilledpolygon($img,array(22,21,20,24,39,35,41,32),4,$orng3);
imagefilledpolygon($img,array(33,10,31,12,43,30,45,28),4,$orng4);
imagefilledpolygon($img,array(45,5,48,5,51,27,48,27),4,$orng5);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
?>
```

Example:
[image: StackOverflow logo drawn in PHP]

Comment: Use variable functions: `$a = 'imagecolorallocate';$r =  'imagefilledrectangle'; $p = 'imagefilledpolygon';` which allows you to reduce the code substantially: `$p(...);$p(...);...`.

Comment: Here is a [700 character gist](http://pastie.org/4611937) down from the 1000+ characters here.

Answer (score 4):

### R

Not the prettiest solution but it returns the requested output.

```
library(grid)
my.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("grey57","orange"))(6)
png("StackOverflow_Logo.png", width=300, height=300)
pushViewport(viewport(x=0.5, y=0.5, w=unit(100, "points"), h=unit(100, "points")))
grid.polygon(x=unit(c(10, 0, 0, 100, 100, 90, 90, 10),"points"), 
             y=unit(c(50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 50, 10, 10),"points"),
             default.units="points", gp=gpar(col = "grey57", fill="grey57"))
grid.rect(vp=viewport(x=0.5, y=0.3, w=unit(70, "points"), h=unit(10, "points")), 
          gp=gpar(col = "grey57", fill="grey57"))

grid.rect(vp=viewport(x=0.52, y=0.52, w=unit(70, "points"), h=unit(10, "points"), angle=-10), 
          gp=gpar(col = my.palette[2], fill=my.palette[2]))

grid.rect(vp=viewport(x=0.58, y=0.78, w=unit(70, "points"), h=unit(10, "points"), angle=-20), 
          gp=gpar(col = my.palette[3], fill=my.palette[3]))

grid.rect(vp=viewport(x=0.70, y=1.05, w=unit(70, "points"), h=unit(10, "points"), angle=-35), 
          gp=gpar(col = my.palette[4], fill=my.palette[4]))

grid.rect(vp=viewport(x=0.90, y=1.25, w=unit(70, "points"), h=unit(10, "points"), angle=-55), 
          gp=gpar(col = my.palette[5], fill=my.palette[5]))

grid.rect(vp=viewport(x=1.15, y=1.38, w=unit(70, "points"), h=unit(10, "points"), angle=-70), 
          gp=gpar(col = my.palette[6], fill=my.palette[6]))
dev.off()
```

[image: logo]

Answer (score 2):

### Scala

```
object LogoCanvas extends javax.swing.JPanel {

  import java.awt._

    def viereck (g: Graphics, points: scala.List[(Int, Int)]) = {
      val polygon = new Polygon ()
      points.foreach (p => polygon.addPoint (10 * p._1, 400 - 10 * p._2))
      g.fillPolygon (polygon)           
    }

  override def paint (g: Graphics) = {
    g.setColor (Color.GRAY);
    // ablage
    viereck (g, scala.List ((2, 1), (2, 11), (3, 11), (3, 1)))
    viereck (g, scala.List ((2, 1), (2, 2), (23, 2), (23, 1)))
    viereck (g, scala.List ((23, 1), (23, 11), (24, 11), (24, 1)))
    // blaetter flach
    viereck (g, scala.List ((5, 5), (5, 6), (21, 6), (21, 5)))
    viereck (g, scala.List ((5, 9), (5, 10), (21, 10), (21, 9)))
    // blaetter schraeg
    g.setColor (Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    viereck (g, scala.List ((7, 22), (8, 23), (21, 13), (21, 12)))
    viereck (g, scala.List ((12, 28), (13, 29), (22, 15), (21, 14)))
    // blaetter steil
    g.setColor (Color.ORANGE);
    viereck (g, scala.List ((18, 34), (19, 34), (23, 17), (22, 16)))
    viereck (g, scala.List ((24, 36), (25, 36), (25, 17), (24, 17)))
  }

  import javax.swing._

  def main (args: Array [String]) : Unit = {
    val jf = new JFrame ("Stackoverflow!")  
    jf.setSize (350, 520)
    jf.setLocationRelativeTo (null)
    jf.setBackground (Color.BLACK)
    jf.add (LogoCanvas)
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation (WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) 
    jf.setVisible (true)            
  }
}
```

[image: Stackoverflow logo on black background]

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

```js
var c=document.getElementById('c'),x=c.getContext('2d'),i=0
c.width=c.height=140
x.scale(5,5)
x.fillStyle="#999"
x.fillRect(3,26,14,2)
x.fillRect(1,18,2,10)
x.fillRect(17,18,2,10)
for(;i<6;){x.fillStyle="#"+"999a96b95c94d93f90".substr(i*3,3)
x.save()
x.translate(i*i/2,22-i*6)
x.rotate(i++/5)
x.fillRect(5,0,10,2)
x.restore()}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```